# Confusing on WebAssembly's Element section

Tags: webassembly

What's the difference of the following two expressions in WebAssembly?

BTW, I see that an element segment consists of several parts including offset and length of a given table, so which field is the corresponding "length" of the given table in the following two expressions?

`(elem 0 (offset (i32.const 0)) $f $f)
(elem 0 (i32.const 0) $f $f)`

The cases  show above come from the official testcases: https://github.com/WebAssembly/testsuite/blob/master/elem.wast

Answer (score 1):

They are equivalent. The latter is a shorthand for the former when the offset "expression" consists of only one instruction.

Comment: so, which field is correspond to the "length" of the given table in these two element segments? the "i32.const 0" is just the offset of the given table.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. The table has already been defined with a length, the segment definition does not need to repeat it. The length of the segment itself is the number of elements it contains.